# building android source for pixel 6

Tags: android-source

I'm trying to build grapheneos for pixel 6 with custom bootanimation.
I created the bootanimation.zip file according to instructions but can't figure out the location to put it in. Since the usual location, system/media/bootanimation.zip is giving me an Error:

offending entries: system/media/bootanimation.zip

besides this, the build also fails.
Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong ?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZD0h.png)

Answer (score 0):

If it is still relevant, I may have an answer for you.
There's a mechanism that prevents you from doing something to the system partition from the product makefile in some cases.
The solution to your specific situation might be different, and there are also suggested solutions in the link below.

If you have something that is a part of the system partition, and is not a product specific thing, you can also add it to:

build/make/target/product/generic_system.mk

instead of the product specific makefile

[Here is a link explaining this mechanism](https://source.android.com/docs/core/bootloader/partitions/product-interfaces#about-the-artifact-path-requirements)